# Do Angular Elements with `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom work` in IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, web-component

Is Angular Elements capable of creating Web Components that can run in IE11 when the view encapsulation is set to `ShadowDom`? Does it require manually added polyfills?

The documentation suggests that you just need to `ng add @angular/elements` and compile the project in both ES2015 and ES5. https://angular.io/guide/elements#browser-support-for-custom-elements

I've tried this with Angular 9 and it doesn't load in IE11.

I can get a standard web component to load in IE11 using https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills
It stands to reason that if Angular is generating a true custom element it should be able to work too.

Does anyone have an Angular Element, ShadowDOM, IE11 version working or is it just not possible.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

<s>Since, Internet Explorer does not support ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), first, we need to configure the Angular 9 application to build in ES5 mode. Then, install the polyfill for the Angular Elements .</s>

Please refer to the following steps:

1. Create a new tsconfig tsconfig-es5.app.json next to tsconfig.app.json with the below contents:

   ```
   {
       "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
       "compilerOptions": {
           "target": "es5" 
       }
   }
   ```
2. In the angular.json add two new configuration section under the build and serve target to provide a new tsconfig (the es5 node, please remember to change the "yourAppName" to  your application name).

   ```
   "build": {
       "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
       "options": {
           ...
       },
       "configurations": {
       "production": {
           ...
       },
       "es5": {
           "tsConfig": "./tsconfig.es5.json"
       }
       }
   },
   "serve": {
       "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
       "options": {
           ...
       },
       "configurations": {
       "production": {
       ...
       },
       "es5": {
           "browserTarget": "yourAppName:build:es5"
       }
       }
   },
   ```
3. Use this command to install the Angular Elements polyfill

   ```
   `ng add @angular/elements `
   ```
4. Run the serve with this configuration using the below command.

   ```
   `ng serve --configuration es5`
   ```

**Edit**:

With reference to [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23636), it seems that angular element still doesn't support Shadow DOM in IE browser. I suggest you could feedback this issue to [Angular forum](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues), and wish them to add the support for Shadow DOM with Angular element in IE browser

Comment: When you run a --prod build of an Angular 9 project it generates ES5 bundles. @angular/elements doesn't support Shadow Dom. Only view encapsulation emulation.

Comment: @moefinley, please check my edit, it seems that the Angular element still doesn't support Shadow DOM in IE browser. I suggest you could feedback this issue to [Angular forum](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues).